# select min price in laravel with relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on Laravel model relation and I don't know how can I select min price in eloquent model relation.

Basically `ProductVariationModel` has multiple price and I want to fetch minimum price.
I have created a relation with `ProductModel`

this is my code:

```
$price= $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductVariationModel','product_id')->min('price');

   return $price;
```

but I did not get result, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think something wrong with the relation, can you share you models?

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain this, in your `Product` model if you create a `variations()` method which has a `hasMany` relation like this

```
public function variations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductVariationModel','product_id');
}
```

If you called this method as a relation like `$product->variations` it will return all variations of this product, but if you call it as `$product->variations()` it will return an instance of `HasMany` relation class.

Now when you added `->min('price')` at the end of the `hasMany` statement the `variations()` becomes a method not a relation so you need to call it as `$product->variations()`

> Note the difference in these two scienarios

```
public function variations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductVariationModel','product_id');
}

// in your controller you can do

$product->variations()->min('price');
```

```
public function variations() // which should be named to "minimumVariation"
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductVariationModel','product_id')->min('price');
}

// in your controller you can do

$product->variations();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** collections simple */
$min = collect([['foo' => 10], ['foo' => 20]])->min('foo');

/** query */
ProductVariationModel::query()->where('product_id','=',1)->min('price')


/** model relation */

public function variations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductVariationModel::class);
}

public function minPrice()
{
    return $this->variations()->min('price');
}
```

**The function of min is as above. Only you have to specify where you want to use it. When you use hasMany, the output is in the form of Collections, where you can use the min function and see the desired output.**

Answer (score 0):

```php
  
public function productVariations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductVariationModel');
}

public function getMinPrice()
{
    return $this->productVariations()->min('price');
}
```

OR

```php
public function getMinPrice()
{
    return $this->productVariations()->orderBy('price')->limit(1);
}
```